# How to install app on Gear S2 via Tizen Studio?

Tags: tizen-web-app, samsung-gear-s2, tizen-sdk, tizen-studio, tizen-certificate

I am new to developing Tizen apps for the Gear S2. I've been through the tutorial but can't get my app installed on my Gear S2.

I'm using Tizen Studio 1.0.1 in Mac OS Sierra (10.12.1), and a newly bought Gear S2.

I've installed the Extension SDK (Samsung Certificate Extension and Samsung Wearable Extension), then created a certificate through the Certificate Manager (Author Certificate and a Distributor Certificate), connected my Gear S2 via Wifi (same network as my computer), set "Permit to install application" by selecting (right click) the device identifier in the connection explorer, and finally set a configuration in the "Run as" option from the Project menu.

But I get an error every time I try to install it and run it on my device:

`$ sdb -s 192.168.2.14:26101 install myapp.wgt
[...]
__return_cb req_id[107100002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[6U1GRaNlHz] key[error] val[81] error message: Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate
__return_cb req_id[107100002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[6U1GRaNlHz] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : Unknown Error [81] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [1225]ms`

Works fine on the emulator though..

I may have messed around with the certificate... Indeed I removed the first certificate I created because it wasn't working and tried to create a new one following the documentation reco, but actually it might just be because I need to register it. How can I do that?

Any other ideas what I miss or did wrong, and how to solve it?
The Tizen documentation isn't really helping...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of error? Add it to the post.

Comment: The command : `sdb -s 192.xxx.x.xx:26101 install myapp.wgt` returned : `__return_cb req_id[23210002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[6U1GRaNlHz] key[error] val[81] error message: Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate` and I think I messed around with the certificate... Indeed I removed the first certificate I created because it wasn't working and tried to create a new one, but actually it might just be because I need to register it. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you make certificate from samsung certification process? Check your certificate is from samsung.
If you make certificate with only sdk it is run only emulator not real device.
You can choose Samsung certificate creation process on certificate menu.

---

You can choose it in menu `tools` -> `Certificate Manager` and

[image]

click `+` in certificate manager and

[image]

click `Samsung` and make samsung certificate.

As @Osana noted; If you do not see the "Select the type of certificate profile" screen, that means you're missing the Samsung Certificate Extension package. Go to `Tools -> Package manager`. Then, go to Extension SDK and install the Samsung Certificate Extension package.

Comment: I can't find any _certificate menu_ all I have is the _Certificate Manager_ from the _tools_ menu, but there is no option in the certificate process creation that allows to choose _Samsung certificate creation process_ Where can I find it in Tizen Studio v1.0.1?

Comment: Thanks! Works just fine! :)

Comment: I feel compelled to note I had the following problem with a profile after fixing this cert problem. This forum solved it. http://developer.samsung.com/forum/thread/watch-profile-error-sdb/201/290176?boardName=SDK&startId=zzzzz~

Comment: If you do not see the "Select the type of certificate profile" screen, that means you're missing the Samsung Certificate Extension package. Go to Tools -> Package manager. Then, go to Extension SDK and install the Samsung Certificate Extension package.

Comment: @Onosa I think this is worth an extra answer

Comment: @lee is correct. After fixing the Samsung cert issue I was still getting the same error because I was mistakenly targetting the wrong SDK version. Migrating the project didn't work, I had to start a new project from scratch with correct version, and then it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

1. Make it sure that, when you select **Permit to install application**, it shows a popup with the message **Succeeded to upload certificate**.
2. Set the device time according to your development PC.
3. Go to Project Properties->Tizen Settings->Platform and select ARMv7-a as the architecture.

[image]

Moreover, follow the steps carefully in [this link](https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-tizen/getting-certificates/create.html).

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 OK, but I don't see where to select ARMv7 fro the project properties, I can't find the "Tizen Settings" or "Platform" (I am very new to Tizen and Tizen Sutdio...)

Comment: Check the modified answer

Comment: OK I found out why I didn't find it in the first place, my sample app is a web app not native. So I went through all these steps again but with a sample native app and I got an error installing the app on the gear : `processing result : SIGNATURE_VERIFICATION_FAILED [23] failed` Looks like I've messed around with certificate or I have to register the certificate somehow, but I don't know how ? Thanks.