# Deploying Tizen app to Gear S2: Non trusted certificate is used

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk

After getting Tizen Studio to work, I am (unsuccessfully) attempting to deploy a sample app to a Samsung Gear S2. The app is one of the samples and I've set up the certificates for use on commercial devices as explained in the instructions.

When I select "Permit to install applications" I get the correct success response and I can also see that the `device-profile.xml` is on the device with the correct DUID.

However, attempting to deploy the app (both from the IDE and via sdb) still results in an error:

```
tizen@buerk:~/tizen-studio/tools$ ./sdb install ../../workspace/FirstExample/FirstExample.wgt                                                                                                                                                                
WARNING: Your data is to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could be read by others.
pushed               FirstExample.wgt   100%       1681KB       0KB/s
1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
../../workspace/FirstExample/FirstExample.wgt   553KB/s (1721589 bytes in 3.035s)
path is /opt/usr/apps/tmp/FirstExample.wgt
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[start] val[install]
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[install_percent] val[3]
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[install_percent] val[22]
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[install_percent] val[25]
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[install_percent] val[33]
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[error] val[81] error message: Non trusted certificate is used. Register valid certificate
__return_cb req_id[21310002] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[RGUVa9zGKK] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : Unknown Error [81] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [2180]ms
```

What else could possibly be wrong?

Comment: And yes, I've seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742515/how-to-install-app-on-gear-s2-via-tizen-studio).

Answer (score 3):

You need samsung certificate.
Application with Certificate that created in Tizen Studio can be run only Emulator.
Use Samsung Certificate if you want to run application on real device.

Refer [this my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742515/how-to-install-app-on-gear-s2-via-tizen-studio/40755444#40755444).

Comment: I've made it pretty clear that I have the correct certificate already.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to deploy on mine (I use CLI sdk on GNU/linux), please detail which version of tizen-studio + packages (cert-addon) you are using,
some hints at :

- https://wiki.tizen.org/wiki/SDK#error_81

Comment: Yes, I've seen all those posts, they don't seem to apply to me. I'm using Tizen Studio 1.0.1 for Ubuntu. The entire SDK for the latest Wearable as well as the Certificate Extension is installed. As I said, I did create a certificate for commercial devices (going through the Samsung sign-in process etc.).

Comment: I should also explicitly note that I can connect to the device and inspect its contents. Uploading the certificates also seems to work fine. Just attempting to install the app fails.

Comment: Check some hints at:
https://wiki.iotivity.org/tizen#sign

Maybe this should be copied to tizen wiki too.

find me on IRC I'll like to assist you and do that in parallel

Comment: So from another laptop it worked just fine. I don't know why it doesn't work from the other one. I have a theory that it had to do with my laptop being connected to a VPN, I'll have to verify that.