# Tizen development in Visual Studio stuck with "Initializing Debugger" dialog

Tags: visual-studio, tizen, tizen-emulator

I I started a new TizenWearableApp in VS 2019, started the Tizen-Emulator and hit run.

The output from Tizen shows the successful build and that the app is signed with Default Certificates. After that, the last printed line is the full path to the .tpk file and a Microsoft Visual Studio Dialog with "Initializing Debugger"...
stuck state screenshot -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/di2YM.jpg

After that nothing more happens. I can press the cancle button and can then see in the Output the following which didn´t help me:

```
: <<< Start debugging "org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4" >>>
: Try to terminate running application: org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4
: No application to be terminated: 255
    WARNING: Your data are to be sent over an unencrypted connection and could be read by others.
    pushed org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4-1.0.0.tpk     0%          0KB       0KB/s
    pushed org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4-1.0.0.tpk   100%         19KB       0KB/s
    1 file(s) pushed. 0 file(s) skipped.
    D:\repos\Tizen\TizenWearableAppV4\TizenWearableAppV4\bin\Debug\tizen40\org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4-1.0.0.tpk   447KB/s (19702 bytes in 0.042s)
    path is /home/owner/share/tmp/sdk_tools/org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4-1.0.0.tpk
    processing result : Operation not allowed [-4] failed
Package found on the target system: "lldb-3.8.1-i686" (tar.gz)
 : Launching org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4
 : 'org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4' is dependent on 'org.tizen.example.TizenWearableAppV4-1.0.0.tpk'.
 : ... launch failed
```

I hope anybody can help me to fix that problem (i got it already working a few month back on this machine).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that whole problem occurs when i try to run/debug the app on a connected watch or the emulator

Comment: The message also says **processing result : Operation not allowed [-4] failed**. You may search for the error and what I found is that *may be* you've not installed the default certificate correctly. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994548/tizen-app-not-installing-on-device/41003293#41003293) answer and [this](https://developer.tizen.org/zh-hans/forums/sdk-ide/no-certificate-profil-permit-install-application-was-found-workspace-device-manager?langswitch=zh-hans) one too.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?  I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/Samsung/build-task-tizen/blob/master/doc/tizen.net.sdk-signing-tpk.md

Here is the page that helped me. I had the same problem but don't want to build from tizen.bat every time. The solution in the above document that worked for me was to close Visual Studio and open the *.csproj file in my solution then add the following replacing with the directory of the certificates I created and my passwords:

```
<PropertyGroup>
 <AuthorPath>author_test.p12</AuthorPath>
 <AuthorPass>author_test</AuthorPass>
 <DistributorPath>tizen-distributor-signer.p12</DistributorPath>
 <DistributorPass>tizenpkcs12passfordsigner</DistributorPass>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just put it below any other Property Group tags. Open Visual Studio again and it should build using the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same. The reason was in certificate signed with wrong distributor - for physical devices (not emulated) you need Samsung distributor certificate. You need to do:

1. Install Samsung Certificate Extension in Tizen package manager
2. Open Certificate manager
3. Run certificate profile wizard and select Samsung option
4. Follow wizard

Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755444/4165898